# datatable show only specific columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dt

I have a dataframe with a relatevly large number of columns.

I want to use the DT package to show only a handful of columns. I haven't found any better way of doing this other than the fixedColumns argument, which allows only for numerical referencing.

The problem I have is that I want to show only, say, columns 5, 15 and 30.

Rather than listing all other 97 columns, I've tried the following:

```
 columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets = c(-5, -15, -30)))
```

Obviouslly, this fails to hide all columns other than 5, 15 and 30. The entire code is below.

```
datatable(
  shared_df, rownames = FALSE, extensions = c('Buttons', 'FixedColumns'), class = 'cell-border stripe', options = list(
    dom = 'Bfrtip',
    scrollX = TRUE,
    fixedColumns = TRUE,
    columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets = c(-1, -2, -3, -4, -5))),
    buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print')
  )
)
```

Any clues?

Comment: What's wrong with `shared_df[, c(5, 15, 30)]`?

Comment: it's not working. I get the following error: object of type 'environment' is not subsettable. The argument asks for a numeric input, not a dataframe.

Comment: Just to clarify. I'm using shared_df <- SharedData$new(dataframe) from the crosstalk package. That's why object is not dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem like this:

```
a <- 1:96 
remove <- c (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 30, 31, 32, 33)

datatable(
  shared_df, rownames = FALSE, extensions = c('Buttons', 'FixedColumns'), class = 'cell-border stripe', options = list(
    dom = 'Bfrtip',
    scrollX = TRUE,
    fixedColumns = TRUE,
    columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets = a[! a %in% remove])),
    buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print')
  )
) %>%
  formatStyle('pl_h_interni',  color = 'white', backgroundColor = 'red', fontWeight = 'bold') %>%
  formatStyle('nov_iznos_h_interni',  color = 'white', backgroundColor = 'green', fontWeight = 'bold')  %>%
  formatStyle('star_iznos_h_interni',  color = 'white', backgroundColor = 'gray', fontWeight = 'bold')
```

Comment: You can also use : ```targets = seq(96)[! seq(96) %in% remove]```